# OpenTelemetry Python Instrumentation dbapi is not capturing the odbc database commands

Tags: python, instrumentation, open-telemetry, python-db-api

I am trying to capture the database commands using Instrumentation DBapi, but i don't see anything to be reported to Jaeger. I am accessing database using pyodbc and pandas and i see while debugging that no exception is occurred and data returned from the database. I have configured Jaeger in my local docker and I see that I am able to send there data if I use the simple getting started examples:

```
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("foo"): 
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("bar"): 
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("baz"): 
    print("Hello world from OpenTelemetry Python!")
```

I assume that Instrumentation DBapi is the correct library for pyodbc connections to database (i am using Azure SQL Server). Is there any better library?

I am running Python 3.7.8. 64 bit. Requirements.txt is attached (at the bottom). Keep in mind that these are the libraries of the main - bigger program. I was able to keep only a small part of it - attached below, to reproduce the issue easily.

Steps to reproduce
Try to run the code above. You need to adjust the database access and sql command.

What is the expected behavior?
Based on my recent experience using OpenTelemetry in .NET, i would expect to see the database command being captured and send information to Jaeger

What is the actual behavior?
The database command is ignored.

Am I doing something wrong or it is a genuine issue?

Thank you in advance!

**Requirements.txt**

```html
aniso8601==9.0.1
api==0.0.7
asgiref==3.4.1
attrs==20.3.0
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Deprecated==1.2.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask-Testing==0.8.1
grpcio==1.39.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==4.0.0
influxdb==5.3.1
install==1.3.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jsonschema==3.2.0
Logentries==0.17
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==1.0.2
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.19.3
opentelemetry-api==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-proto-grpc==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-thrift==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin-json==1.4.1
opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin-proto-http==1.4.1
opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.23b2
opentelemetry-instrumentation-dbapi==0.23b2
opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask==0.23b2
opentelemetry-instrumentation-requests==0.23b2
opentelemetry-instrumentation-wsgi==0.23b2
opentelemetry-sdk==1.4.1
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.23b2
opentelemetry-util-http==0.23b2
pandas==1.1.4
protobuf==3.17.3
pyodbc==4.0.30
pyrsistent==0.17.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.25.0
six==1.15.0
smart-open==5.0.0
thrift==0.13.0
timeloop==1.0.2
typing==3.7.4.3
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.2
Werkzeug==0.15.5
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.4.1
```

**Python Code**

```
import os
from smart_open import open
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort
from flask_restplus import reqparse, Api, Resource, fields
from datetime import datetime
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import time

import pyodbc
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.flask import FlaskInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.requests import RequestsInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.exporter.jaeger.thrift import JaegerExporter
from opentelemetry.exporter.zipkin.json import ZipkinExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (BatchSpanProcessor)
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.dbapi import trace_integration

pools_connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER;Database=DATABASE_NAME;Uid=USER_NAME;pwd=PASSWORD;"

app = Flask(__name__)

trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())

jaeger_exporter = JaegerExporter(
    agent_host_name="localhost",
    agent_port=6831,
)

zipkin_exporter = ZipkinExporter(
    endpoint="http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans"
    )

trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(jaeger_exporter))
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(zipkin_exporter))

FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)
RequestsInstrumentor().instrument()

trace_integration(pyodbc, "Connection", "odbc")

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

with tracer.start_as_current_span("foo"):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("bar"):
        with tracer.start_as_current_span("baz"):
            print("Hello world from OpenTelemetry Python!")

connection = pyodbc.connect(pools_connection_string, ansi=True, autocommit=True)
sql = """
    with t as 
    (select  GeoAssetID,
                Grade, 
                PriceAtLastUpdate as BunkerPrice, 
                LastUpdated as PriceDate,
                row_number() over (partition by Grade, GeoAssetID order by LastUpdated desc) as row
    from [Rates] bp with (nolock)
    where GeoAssetID in (3763)
    )
    select * from t where row = 1 order by GeoAssetID
"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=connection)

tl = Timeloop()

tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=14400))

tl.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=2180, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Does this happen in all cases or just when you use pandas?

Comment: I haven't tries anything else. Do you have something specific in mind? Unfortunately I am new in python.

Comment: Can you try querying without pandas and see if that works. That way you could potentially isolate the issue to be more precisely.

Comment: I changed the code like this but nothing changed.

`cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.tables()
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row.table_name)`

and 

`cursor = connection.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I finally had to replace "Connection" with "connect".

Replace:
trace_integration(pyodbc, "**Connection**", "odbc")
with
trace_integration(pyodbc, "**connect**", "odbc")

It seems that there is a mistake in the documentation, that will be fixed.

I am closing this issue.